# wacom device java sdk

Tags: java, sdk, tablet-pc, wacom

I have Wacom device STU 500 . I work on a project module for signing pdf files.
I didn't find any Java SDK-API to query the device with . is there an elegant way to do this from java code ?

Comment: Why not use the regular mouse events generated by the tablet.

Comment: Thx for reply , I just didn't figure out how to detect the tablet from a java swing application !

Answer (score 3):

As the previous posts indicate, contact the your regional Wacom office to obtain the SDK. They will email you a '*SDK Approval Form*' where you have to fill in certain details. Once they verify the document as well as your credentials they would send you a link to download the SDK.

Please note that there are two types of SDK's. They are called the '*Low-Level*' SDK and the '*Signature*' SDK by Wacom. The '*Low-Level*' SDK is free and other other isn't. The '*Low-Level*' SDK should suffice unless you need biometric/forensic/security/verification and other capabilities for which you need to select the '*Signature*' SDK.

Since you are specifically asking to sign PDF files, check out [Wacom's 'Sign | Pro PDF' SDK](http://signature.wacom.eu/products/software/sign-i-pro-pdf).

This is a late reply, but I hope it helps you or others working with Wacom.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask Wacom directly to get the existing SDK.

From Wacom FAQ:

> 3.23.      How can I program an STU-300, STU-500, or STU-520 Signature (signpad) Tablet?
>   You can obtain an STU-300, STU-500, or STU-520 SDK to program in C++, C# or Java by contacting Wacom Customer Care in your region.

http://www.wacom.com/en/CustomerCare/HelpRequest/ContactTechnicalSupport.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information here: http://signature.wacom.eu/products/software/signature-sdk.
There´s a contact form where you can ask for the SDKs.